# Memory quota exceeded - Heroku + Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, heroku, puppeteer

I'm quite new to Heroku and node servers, so this might be a very basic question.

I can't access the route using [puppeteer module](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) but I can access the default home page that just renders a view.

I  used `heroku logs -a node-stuff` and I can see the following errors at the very beginning:

```
Process running mem=726M(138.9%)
Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
Error: Failed to launch chrome!
```

The only solution I found so far is restarting the server every time this happens with `heroku restart -a node-stuff`

What's going on?

- How could I fix it?
- How can I liberate memory?

My main route is quite basic:

```
var express = require('express');
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var cors = require('cors')

var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', cors(), function(req, res, next) 
    var scrapePage = async (req, Admin) => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            args: [
                '--no-sandbox',
                '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            ]
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(req.query.url);

        //loading a .js file to use it those functions on page load
        await page.addScriptTag({path: "./models/admin.js"});

        const scrapedData = await page.evaluate(function(){

            //query stuff from window and document variables

            return {
                whatever: here
            };
        });

        await browser.close();
        return scrapedData;    
    };

    const test = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        scrapePage(req, Admin)
        .then(data => {
            res.json(data);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
        });
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I'd imagine puppeteer is fairly memory heavy, and that you need to provision a larger dyno for it. `standard-2x` will give you 1 GB. `performance-m` will give you 2.5 GB.

Comment: It should still find the app, open a support ticket

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert sorry, I removed the `restart` issue, I was using  `-app` instead of `-a`. My mistake :) 
The other issue persist tho.

Comment: @ceejayoz how do I know how much memory do I need? Does it depends on the number of people accessing that route using puppeeter?

Comment: @ceejayoz will a single dyno be enough? When should I change to more than one? I've just updated to `standard-2x`.

Comment: @Alvaro You find out how much memory is needed by experimentation. Multiple dynos helps you when you need to handle multiple concurrent requests; it doesn't give individual requests more RAM to work with.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue and the solution ended up being that I wasn't always running `browser.close()` because of occasional errors within my scraping.  Make sure that you are always closing your browser wrapping your `scrapePage` code in a `try catch finally` and put `browser.close()` in the `finally` block so that it runs no matter the result of your scraping.

Comment: If you see the code I posted you'll notice the `browser.close` there :)

Comment: browser.close() worked for me as i have never used that before. i was using simple web scrapping and got the memory error.